# How can I pass function keys to htop in a tty?

Tags: terminal, console, htop, terminfo

I'm trying to use `htop` in tty1. However, some of the function keys don't appear to work as normal. <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> do nothing, and <kbd>F3</kbd> seems to trigger setup (which should normally be triggered by <kbd>F2</kbd>). In addition, <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd> don't work. Also, when I try and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get out of these screens, I have to press it twice.

In a normal terminal (`terminator`), the function keys work fine. However, I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice here too, so perhaps that's a red herring.

How can I use these function keys in tty1?

### EDIT

In tty1, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F5</kbd>, etc. I get the the following output:

```
^[[[A
^[[[B
^[[[C
^[[[D
^[[[E
```

In `terminator`, I get

```
^[OP
^[OQ
^[OR
^[OS
^[[15~
```

The function keys above this are equivalent (e.g. `^[[17~` for <kbd>F6</kbd>).

### EDIT 2

In response to Stéphane Chazelas's [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198711/how-can-i-pass-function-keys-to-htop-in-a-tty?noredirect=1#comment431783_198711).

- `$TERM` is the same in tty1 as in my "normal", working terminal. It is `xterm-256color`.
- I am not using screen or tmux.
- I am using `htop` 1.0.3, although my first edit seems to point to it being an issue upstream of `htop`.

> "Does `infocmp -L1 | grep key_f` match what those keys send for you?

I'm not sure what you mean by "match what those keys send for you", but I ran this command in both my normal terminal and tty1, and the output was identical, as below.

```
key_f1=\EOP,
key_f10=\E[21~,
key_f11=\E[23~,
key_f12=\E[24~,
key_f13=\E[1;2P,
key_f14=\E[1;2Q,
key_f15=\E[1;2R,
key_f16=\E[1;2S,
key_f17=\E[15;2~,
key_f18=\E[17;2~,
key_f19=\E[18;2~,
key_f2=\EOQ,
key_f20=\E[19;2~,
key_f21=\E[20;2~,
key_f22=\E[21;2~,
key_f23=\E[23;2~,
key_f24=\E[24;2~,
key_f25=\E[1;5P,
key_f26=\E[1;5Q,
key_f27=\E[1;5R,
key_f28=\E[1;5S,
key_f29=\E[15;5~,
key_f3=\EOR,
key_f30=\E[17;5~,
key_f31=\E[18;5~,
key_f32=\E[19;5~,
key_f33=\E[20;5~,
key_f34=\E[21;5~,
key_f35=\E[23;5~,
key_f36=\E[24;5~,
key_f37=\E[1;6P,
key_f38=\E[1;6Q,
key_f39=\E[1;6R,
key_f4=\EOS,
key_f40=\E[1;6S,
key_f41=\E[15;6~,
key_f42=\E[17;6~,
key_f43=\E[18;6~,
key_f44=\E[19;6~,
key_f45=\E[20;6~,
key_f46=\E[21;6~,
key_f47=\E[23;6~,
key_f48=\E[24;6~,
key_f49=\E[1;3P,
key_f5=\E[15~,
key_f50=\E[1;3Q,
key_f51=\E[1;3R,
key_f52=\E[1;3S,
key_f53=\E[15;3~,
key_f54=\E[17;3~,
key_f55=\E[18;3~,
key_f56=\E[19;3~,
key_f57=\E[20;3~,
key_f58=\E[21;3~,
key_f59=\E[23;3~,
key_f6=\E[17~,
key_f60=\E[24;3~,
key_f61=\E[1;4P,
key_f62=\E[1;4Q,
key_f63=\E[1;4R,
key_f7=\E[18~,
key_f8=\E[19~,
key_f9=\E[20~,
```

Comment: On tty1, at the shell prompt, press `Ctrl+V` then `F1`, and see what gets inserted. Repeat for `F2`, `F3`, `F4` and `F5`, and then do the same in terminator. Tell us what you see.

Comment: @Gilles The question has been edited.

Comment: What's the value of `$TERM` in there? Are you using screen or tmux? What version of htop? Does `infocmp -L1 | grep key_f` match what those keys send for you?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've edited the question.

Comment: It should be TERM=linux, the linux virtual console has hardly anything to do with xterm. getty should set $TERM for you,  you should not overwrite it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah that's it! I had in `~/.bashrc` the line `export TERM=xterm-256color`. I now only set this if `$TERM` was already `xterm`. This now works. Please answer and I'll accept.

Comment: You can also configure xterm to use that value for `$TERM`

Comment: OP says they're using `terminator` (one of the VTE wrappers) rather than `xterm`.  As a rule, the VTE wrappers hardcode `TERM=xterm`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey As per my comment above, I previously had `export TERM=xterm-256color` in `~/.bashrc`. Now it only changes `TERM` to this if (as you say) it was previously `TERM=xterm`. This now works fine.

Comment: I understood that (but the previous comment needed a clarification).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By setting:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

you're telling `htop` (and every other visual terminal application that uses the termcap or terminfo database) that your terminal is a 256 colour xterm and not a Linux virtual console.

`htop` will query the terminfo database to know what sequence of characters is sent upon <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>... but will get those for `xterm`.

`xterm` sends different sequences than the Linux virtual console for those keys which you can verify by querying the terminfo database by hand with `infocmp` for instance:

```
$ infocmp -L1 xterm-256color | grep 'key_f[1-5]='
        key_f1=\EOP,
        key_f2=\EOQ,
        key_f3=\EOR,
        key_f4=\EOS,
        key_f5=\E[15~,
$ infocmp -L1 linux | grep 'key_f[1-5]='
        key_f1=\E[[A,
        key_f2=\E[[B,
        key_f3=\E[[C,
        key_f4=\E[[D,
        key_f5=\E[[E,
```

So `htop` will not recognise `\E[[A` as a <kbd>F1</kbd>, it will expect `\EOP` for that.

Here, you don't want to assign values to `$TERM` in `~/.bashrc`. `$TERM` should be set by the terminal emulators (`xterm`, `terminator`) themselves, and by `getty` for Linux virtual consoles (should be `linux` there).

If you're not happy with the value that a particular terminal emulator picks for `$TERM`, that's the configuration of that terminal emulators you should update.

Comment: On mac, just open Terminal preferences and change from "ansi" to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  In my case, KiTTY (fork of PuTTY) was setting `$TERM` to `xterm-256color`, but was set up to use `ESC[n~` function keys.  I changed the function keys to use `XTerm R6` in the settings and its all working now.